# Error: [$injector:modulerr] Failed to instantiate module ng due to: this is null after upgrading to angular 1.5

Tags: angularjs

After upgrading to angular 1.5.7 from 1.4.9, I'm getting the following error:

I have **AngularJs** as a last script tag to avoid any conflicts with my application code.

```
Error: [$injector:modulerr] Failed to instantiate module ng due to:
this is null
$CompileProvider@https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.5.7/angular.js:7656:3
.bind/<@http://localhost/wro/appJS.js?RESOURCE_VERSION=12345-0:23:968
instantiate@https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.5.7/angular.js:4724:14
provider@https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.5.7/angular.js:4538:1
supportObject/<@https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.5.7/angular.js:4530:16
ngModule@https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.5.7/angular.js:2564:7
invoke@https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.5.7/angular.js:4709:16
runInvokeQueue@https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.5.7/angular.js:4602:11
loadModules/<@https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.5.7/angular.js:4611:11
forEach@https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.5.7/angular.js:321:11
loadModules@https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.5.7/angular.js:4592:5
createInjector@https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.5.7/angular.js:4514:19
bootstrap/doBootstrap@https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.5.7/angular.js:1751:20
bootstrap@https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.5.7/angular.js:1772:1
angularInit@https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.5.7/angular.js:1657:5
@https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.5.7/angular.js:31468:5
n.Callbacks/j@http://localhost/wro/jqrJS.js?RESOURCE_VERSION=12345-0:6:46277
n.Callbacks/k.fireWith@http://localhost/wro/jqrJS.js?RESOURCE_VERSION=12345-0:6:47095
.ready@http://localhost/wro/jqrJS.js?RESOURCE_VERSION=12345-0:6:48887
I@http://localhost/wro/jqrJS.js?RESOURCE_VERSION=12345-0:6:49078
```

Comment: Angular needs to be loaded before your code so that your code knows what angular is.

Comment: index.html would be helpful in finding the error?

Comment: Loading Angular JS first and upgrading prototype to latest version 1.7.3 resolved this issue.

Answer (score 0):

prototype.js used in my project was conflicting.
Upgrading it to latest version 1.7.3 and then loading jQuery, Angular and then prototype resolved this issue.